# emacs 24.x Recursive 'require' for feature 'magit-simple-keys'

Tags: emacs

I've just upgraded my whole distro and I'm trying to setup my emacs with my previous settings and when using my 'magit' plugin and typing 'M-x magit-status' I get the following error:

```
Recursive `require' for feature `magit-simple-keys'
```

Here is my config (.emacs.d/init.el)

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(setq required-packages
      (list 'mwe-log-commands 'drag-stuff 'flymake-ruby 'flymake-haml 'regex-tool 'mic-paren 'highline 'android-mode 'css-mode 'csv-mode 'apache-mode 'crontab-mode 'emms 'switch-window 'multi-term 'undo-tree 'rvm 'auto-complete 'yasnippet-bundle 'ruby-electric 'rinari 'inf-ruby 'coffee-mode 'yaml-mode 'feature-mode 'scss-mode 'haml-mode 'magit-simple-keys))
(dolist (package required-packages)
  (when (not (package-installed-p package))
    (package-refresh-contents)
    (package-install package)))

;; Setup external directory variable
(setq elisp-dir
      (expand-file-name "elisp" user-emacs-directory))
(setq elisp-external-dir
      (expand-file-name "external" elisp-dir))

;; Add external projects to load path
(add-to-list 'load-path elisp-external-dir)

(dolist (project (directory-files elisp-external-dir t "\\w+"))
  (when (file-directory-p project)
    (add-to-list 'load-path project)))


; Keybinding
(global-set-key [f1] 'twit)
(global-set-key [f2] 'gist-region-or-buffer)
(global-set-key [f3] 'switch-window)
(global-set-key [f4] 'magit-display-log)
(global-set-key [f5] 'magit-status)
(global-set-key [f6] 'multi-term)
(global-set-key [f7] 'split-window-vertically)
(global-set-key [f8] 'next-multiframe-window)
;; f9 is taken by git-status somewhere.
(global-set-key [f10] 'undo-tree-visualize)
(global-set-key [f12] 'switch-full-screen)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x f") 'rinari-find-file-in-project)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g") 'rinari-rgrep)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c I") 'irc)

;fullscreen mode
(defun switch-full-screen ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -btoggle,fullscreen"))

;; Allow using mouse thumb button to browse URLs
(global-set-key [mouse-10] 'browse-url-at-mouse)

; stop emacs from contaminating each directory with semantic.cache
(setq semanticdb-default-save-directory "/tmp")

; General settings
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(menu-bar-mode 1)         ;; enable the menu bar
(tool-bar-mode -1)        ; Disable tool-bar
(display-battery-mode)
(setq column-number-mode t)
(display-time)
(setq backup-inhibited t) ;; disable backup

;; Org-mode options
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-visual-line-mode)
;; (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-autosave-settings)
;; (defun my-org-mode-autosave-settings ()
;;   (set (make-local-variable 'auto-save-visited-file-name) t)
;;   (setq auto-save-interval 20))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org$" . org-mode))
(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org/"))
(setq org-directory "~/Dropbox/org")
(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "~/Dropbox/org/inbox.org");; new notes will be stored here
(setq org-support-shift-select t)
(setq org-mobile-directory "~/Dropbox/MobileOrg")         ;; Set to <your Dropbox root directory>/MobileOrg.

;; Set color
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "black" :foreground "white" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 98 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "DejaVu Sans Mono")))))

; Auto complete settings
(setq hippie-expand-try-functions-list
      '(try-complete-abbrev
    try-complete-file-name
    try-expand-dabbrev))

; -------------------- Custom Settings --------------------
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(column-number-mode t)
 '(display-battery-mode t)
 '(display-time-mode t)
 '(ecb-options-version "2.32")
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(org-agenda-files (quote ("~/Dropbox/org")) t)
 '(rails-ws:default-server-type "mongrel")
 '(send-mail-function (quote smtpmail-send-it))
 '(smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.googlemail.com")
 '(smtpmail-smtp-service "smtp")
 '(tool-bar-mode nil)
 '(tooltip-mode nil))

; -------------------- File plugins --------------------
; Interactively Do Things
(ido-mode t)                            

; tramp - remote ssh editing
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")

; -------------------- Rails setting files --------------------
(require 'yaml-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.yml$" . yaml-mode))

; -------------------- Rails minor plugin -------------------- 
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)

;; https://github.com/remvee/emacs-rails
;; Currently this interfers with auto complete, using rinari instead
;; automatically adds end to blocks.
(require 'rails)            

;; Rinari - Rails plugin
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/rinari/")
(require 'rinari)
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (defadvice ruby-mode-set-encoding
              (around ruby-mode-set-encoding-disable activate) nil)))

; -------------------- Rails Views -------------------- 
; haml-sass
(require 'haml-mode nil 't)
 (add-hook 'haml-mode-hook
  '(lambda () (setq tab-width 2)))
(setq scss-compile-at-save nil)

; stylesheets
(autoload 'css-mode "css-mode")
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.css\\'" . css-mode) auto-mode-alist))

; html2haml function to convert current buffer to haml
(defun haml-ify ()
  "run html2haml on current buffer"
  (interactive)
  (setf filename buffer-file-name)
  (setf newfilename (concat filename ".haml"))
  (save-buffer)
  (shell-command (concat
    "html2haml " filename " > " newfilename))
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
  (delete-file filename)
  (find-file newfilename))
;; -------------------- Rails Testing -------------------- 
;; Cucumber
(require 'feature-mode)

;; -------------------- Rails Tools -------------------- 
;; Check out abbrev-mode instead as it seems lighter.
(require 'snippet)

;; -------------------- Ruby plugins -------------------- 
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("Capfile" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("Gemfile" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("Rakefile" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("god" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("Guardfile" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rake\\'" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rb\\'" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ru\\'" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html.erb\\'" . html-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ejs\\'" . html-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.eco\\'" . html-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hamlc\\'" . haml-mode))

;; Ruby-electric
(require 'ruby-electric)
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'ruby-electric-mode)

;; Issues under some compiles of emacs
;; (require 'ruby-electric)
;; (add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
;;           (lambda()
;;             (add-hook 'local-write-file-hooks
;;                       '(lambda()
;;                          (save-excursion
;;                            (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
;;                            ;(delete-trailing-whitespace)
;;                            )))
;;             (set (make-local-variable 'indent-tabs-mode) 'nil)
;;             (set (make-local-variable 'tab-width) 2)
;;             (imenu-add-to-menubar "IMENU")
;;             (require 'ruby-electric)
;;             (ruby-electric-mode t)))

;; Inferior Ruby Mode
(autoload 'inf-ruby "inf-ruby" "Run an inferior Ruby process" t)
(autoload 'inf-ruby-keys "inf-ruby" "" t)
(eval-after-load 'ruby-mode '(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'inf-ruby-keys))

;; -------------------- SQL --------------------
(defun my-sql-interactive-mode-hook ()
  (setq tab-width 8))
(add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook 'my-sql-interactive-mode-hook)
(require 'sql)
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)


;; -------------------- Autocomplete --------------------
;; Use with Rsense for Ruby autocomplete:
;; http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/
;; Follow instructions on: http://itstickers.blogspot.com/2010/11/all-about-emacs.html
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)

;; Rsense
(setq rsense-home "/opt/rsense-0.3")
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat rsense-home "/etc"))
(require 'rsense)

;; Rsense + Autocomplete
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-rsense-method)
            (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-rsense-constant)))

;; Complete by C-c .
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c .") 'rsense-complete)))

;; RVM in emacs
;; (require 'rvm)
;; (rvm-use-default) ;; use rvm’s default ruby for the current Emacs session

;; Switch windows easier when you have 3 or more.
(require 'switch-window)

;; gist
(require 'gist)
(setq gist-authentication-function 'gist-basic-authentication)

(setq the-secrets-file
      (expand-file-name "secrets.el" user-emacs-directory))
(when (file-exists-p the-secrets-file)
  (load the-secrets-file))

;; highline-mode
(require 'highline) 
(defun highline-mode-on ()
  (highline-mode 1)) 
;; Turn on local highlighting for Dired (C-x d) 
(add-hook 'dired-after-readin-hook #'highline-mode-on) 
;; Turn on local highlighting for list-buffers (C-x C-b) 
(defadvice list-buffers (after highlight-line activate) (save-excursion (set-buffer "*Buffer List*") (highline-mode-on)))

;; mic-paren - advanced highlighting of matching parentheses
(paren-activate)

;; flyspell
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (flyspell-mode)
        (setq flyspell-issue-message-flag 'nil)))
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (flyspell-prog-mode)
        (setq flyspell-issue-message-flag 'nil)))

;; flymake haml
(add-hook 'haml-mode-hook 'flymake-haml-load)


;; undo
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'undo-tree-mode)

;; multi-term
;; (setq term-default-fg-color "#aaa")  

;; Upgrade all packages
(defun package-update-all ()
  "Update all packages"
  (interactive)
  (dolist (elt package-alist)
    (let* ((name (car elt))
           (file-name (symbol-name name))
           (available-pkg (assq name package-archive-contents))
           (available-version (and available-pkg
                                   (package-desc-vers (cdr available-pkg))))
           (current-version (package-desc-vers (cdr elt)))
           )
      (when (and available-version
                 (version-list-< current-version available-version))
        (message "Updating to: %s - %s" file-name
                 (package-version-join available-version))
        (package-install name)
        (package-delete file-name (package-version-join current-version))))))


;; Music player
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/external/bongo")
(setq bongo-global-lastfm-mode t)
(autoload 'bongo "bongo"
  "Start Bongo by switching to a Bongo buffer." t)

;; Volume manager (Use 'v' in bongo music player)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/external/volume-el")
(autoload 'volume "volume"
   "Tweak your sound card volume." t)

;; Twitter mode
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/external/twitter-mode")
(require 'twittering-mode)
(setq twittering-icon-mode t)  
(setq twittering-timer-interval 40) 
(setq twittering-url-show-status nil) 
(add-hook 'twittering-edit-mode-hook (lambda () (ispell-minor-mode) (flyspell-mode)))
(setq twittering-use-master-password t) ;; Don't prompt for authorisation. 

;; drag-stuff
(require 'drag-stuff)

;; coffee-mode
(defun coffee-custom ()
  "coffee-mode-hook"
 (set (make-local-variable 'tab-width) 2))

;; (define-key coffee-mode-map [(meta r)] 'coffee-compile-buffer)
;; (define-key coffee-mode-map [(meta R)] 'coffee-compile-region)

(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook
  '(lambda() (coffee-custom)))

;; Don't ask to save abbrevs
(setq save-abbrevs 'silently)


;; log commands.
;; M-x mwe:open-command-log-buffer
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (function mwe:log-keyboard-commands))

;; screensaver
(setq zone-when-idle t)


;; IRC reconnect
(eval-after-load 'rcirc
  '(defun-rcirc-command reconnect (arg)
     "Reconnect the server process."
     (interactive "i")
     (unless process
       (error "There's no process for this target"))
     (let* ((server (car (process-contact process)))
        (port (process-contact process :service))
        (nick (rcirc-nick process))
        channels query-buffers)
       (dolist (buf (buffer-list))
     (with-current-buffer buf
       (when (eq process (rcirc-buffer-process))
         (remove-hook 'change-major-mode-hook
              'rcirc-change-major-mode-hook)
         (if (rcirc-channel-p rcirc-target)
         (setq channels (cons rcirc-target channels))
           (setq query-buffers (cons buf query-buffers))))))
       (delete-process process)
       (rcirc-connect server port nick
              rcirc-default-user-name
              rcirc-default-full-name
              channels))))

;; Video editor
;; (load "~/.emacs.d/elisp/external/gneve.el")
```

Comment: Try creating a minimal .emacs that gives the same error message. Probably with only magit and magit-simple-keys. This will be easier to help you with a shorter code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was I only need to install 'magit not 'magit-simple-keys.

Comment: I had the  same problem (because I'd installed magit and never used it) and needed to `package-delete` everything related to magit or depending on it, also get my `melpa` in order, re-install only magit and it was all good.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess that you need to update one or other of `magit` and `magit-simple-keys` (and you might as well do both).

I can see that you are installing `magit-simple-keys` via package.el, but not `magit` itself, so you might want to source `magit` from there too in order to try to keep the versions synchronised.